# Slide a view over another iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two views.  View A that is 600 long and in the background and view b that is in the foreground and the same length (600).  I want to have view b partially showing and partly overlapping view A.  when a finger swipes it I would like it to be dragged over view a and be able to have view B cover it and stay in place.  I tried this with a scroll view but can't get it to work.  The views don't have to be 600 long they can be whatever length is needed to cover the whole length of the iPhone.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You don't need a scroll view to get views to move. Just change the position of the view, e.g. by setting its `center` or `frame` property. Use Core Animation to animate the change and make it look snazzy.

Comment: can i get an example?

Comment: This is kind of what you are looking for.
https://github.com/fastred/AHKActionSheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a swipe gesture recognizer to view B:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.viewB addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And then using Core Animation you can animate view B:

```
-(void)swipeRight:(id)sender {
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.viewB.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(600, 0);
    }];
}
```